# Как найти элемент "стрелка" в toolbare?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Ищу код стрелки из toolbara'a. Стрелка делает переход из второго фрагмента в первый. Хочу "повесить" этот код на кнопку (android:id="@+id/button_second")

Скриншот стрелки -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура проекта -
https://github.com/intersk/strelka

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Answer (score 1):

```
binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener () {
    (activity as MainActivity1).onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

по подсказке *woesss* сделал, код работает, но как у начинающего вопрос - почему MainActivity с индексом  **1** ?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28966294/3456124) корректный

Но я вставляю в AppBar свой LinearLayout с горизонтальной ориентацией, втсавляю туда ImageView + Toolbar и делаю всё, что душе угодно: можно делать более гибкие настройки (отступы, фокус повесить для TV, настроить gravity и т.д.) и это отлично работает. ИМХО, гораздо лучше, чем часами искать нужные атрибуты.

Comment: в моем проекте эта стрелка уже есть, просто мне надо eё действие продублировать на кнопку. Но найти эту функцию у себя я не смог

Comment: В `MainActivity` функция `onSupportNavigateUp()` - это не оно?

Comment: при таком коде `binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener { onSupportNavigateUp() }` onSupportNavigateUp выдает ошибку, видимо не видна функция из активити во втором фрагменте

Comment: @jurvrn, найдите эту вашу стрелку и "нажмите" на нее программно. Вам и знать не надо что она там вызывает и как она вообще работает.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()

Comment: просьба подсказать немного подробнее

Comment: @woesss по вашей подсказке сделал код, но вопрос один остался